# Extend HTMLElement prototype

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to extend the prototype of the HTMLElement object in `main.ts`, so that I can use it throughout my whole Angular 6 project.

But I get the `Property 'fadeOut' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function(duration: number = 300): Promise<void> {
  const keyframes: AnimationKeyFrame[] = [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 }];
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const animation: Animation = this.animate(keyframes, duration);
    animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
  });
};
```

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');

HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function(duration = 300) {
  const keyframes = [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 }];
  return this.animate(keyframes, duration).finished
};

circle.fadeOut(2000);
```

```css
#circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0f477f;
 }
```

```html
<div id="circle"></>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Where do I need to put this code so that can I make this method available everywhere?

Do you also see a possibility to make this code cleaner?

Comment: Maybe HTMLElement.prototype['fadeOut'] works.

Comment: If that worked then what the OP tried would work too.

Comment: What exactly does the code that attempts to use the method look like?

Comment: Once you get the prototype thing figured out, I think your function can just be: `function(duration: number = 300) { return this.animate([{opacity:1},{opacity:0}], duration).finished; }`

Comment: I've just added a snippet, so the code works.
@SeanBright You're right! Gotta dive deeper into this amazing API. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is the 'this' inside the Promise is lexical and does not refer to the object anymore, why can't we use the 20 year old var that = this method here?

Comment: @ibowankenobi Yes might be possible, didn't check it. But in the snippet above, you'll see that I've removed the promise and the code works perfectly. The issue is just that the linter doesn't accept it

Comment: Ahh orayt then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a definition to be [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) with the original interface in which you define the extra function to be added to `HTMLElement`

```
interface HTMLElement {
    fadeOut(duration: number): Promise<void>
}

// Will now work 
HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function (duration: number = 300): Promise<void> {
    const keyframes: AnimationKeyFrame[] = [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 }];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const animation: Animation = this.animate(keyframes, duration);
        animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
    });
};
```

If the code is in a module you need to declare the interface in the global namespace

```
declare global {
    interface HTMLElement {
        fadeOut(duration: number): Promise<void>
    }

}
HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOut = function (duration: number = 300): Promise<void> {
    const keyframes: AnimationKeyFrame[] = [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 }];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const animation: Animation = this.animate(keyframes, duration);
        animation.onfinish = () => resolve();
    });
};


export var x;
```

Comment: The code was working from the beginning, but it is more a lint issue. Unfortunately, adding an interface doesn't seem to solve this issue.

Comment: @KodeBryant it's not a lint issue, it's a Typescript compilation issue, the compiler will still emit code on semantic issues. Added a version that will work with modules, should work in your angular app now.

Comment: Works perfectly now, you're awesome!